# Face Recoginition Python open cv

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition, training-data

Is there any way i can make my own train set for face recognition in python ? To be more specific i want to make a train set like an AT&T Face database. I want my camera to take 20 images of each person(30 max) and store it in the separate folders by the name of each person.

```
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
size = 4
fn_haar = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
fn_dir = 'att_faces'
fn_name = sys.argv[1]
path = os.path.join(fn_dir, fn_name)
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
(im_width, im_height) = (112, 92)
haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(fn_haar)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# The program loops until it has 20 images of the face.
count = 0
while count < 20:
    (rval, im) = webcam.read()
    im = cv2.flip(im, 1, 0)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mini = cv2.resize(gray, (gray.shape[1] / size, gray.shape[0] / size))
    faces = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(mini)
    faces = sorted(faces, key=lambda x: x[3])
    if faces:
        face_i = faces[0]
        (x, y, w, h) = [v * size for v in face_i]
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (im_width, im_height))
        pin=sorted([int(n[:n.find('.')]) for n in os.listdir(path)
               if n[0]!='.' ]+[0])[-1] + 1
        cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.png' % (path, pin), face_resize)
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(im, fn_name, (x - 10, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
            1,(0, 255, 0))
        count += 1
    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', im)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do. Do you want opencv to take 30 pictures of a person for you? Or do you have the pictures and do you want to train a detector?

Comment: Can you be more specific where are you facing problems ? Share the piece of code you have written so far ?

Comment: this code is taking 20 pictures of a face detected and saves it in a folder than terminates. I want to edit it. it should take 20 pictures of each face which is detected and saves each face in separate folder. it should not terminate on its own.

Comment: code is added..

Comment: @user3543300 this code is taking 20 pictures of a face detected and saves it in a folder than terminates. I want to edit it. it should take 20 pictures of each face which is detected and saves each face in separate folder. it should not terminate on its own

Comment: @ZdaR this code is taking 20 pictures of a face detected and saves it in a folder than terminates. I want to edit it. it should take 20 pictures of each face which is detected and saves each face in separate folder. it should not terminate on its own

Answer (score 1):

For this, you just need to provide a particular path to save all the image with (.png) or (.bmp) or (.jpg) extension in a sorted manner.

```
# train.py
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
size = 4
fn_haar = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
fn_dir = 'face_data'

fn_name = sys.argv[0]


path = os.path.join(fn_dir, fn_name)

(im_width, im_height) = (112, 92)
haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(fn_haar)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Generate name for image file
pin=sorted([int(n[:n.find('.')]) for n in os.listdir(path)
 if n[0]!='.' ]+[0])[-1] + 1

# Beginning message
print("\n\033[94mThe program will save 20 samples. \
Move your head around to increase while it runs.\033[0m\n")

# The program loops until it has 20 images of the face.
count = 0
pause = 0
count_max = 20
while count < count_max:

  # Loop until the camera is working
  rval = False
  while(not rval):
    # Put the image from the webcam into 'frame'
    (rval, frame) = webcam.read()
    if(not rval):
        print("Failed to open webcam. Trying again...")

# Get image size
height, width, channels = frame.shape

# Flip frame
frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1, 0)

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Scale down for speed
mini = cv2.resize(gray, (int(gray.shape[1] / size), int(gray.shape[0] / size)))

# Detect faces
faces = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(mini)

# We only consider largest face
faces = sorted(faces, key=lambda x: x[3])
if faces:
    face_i = faces[0]
    (x, y, w, h) = [v * size for v in face_i]

    face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (im_width, im_height))

    # Draw rectangle and write name
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
    cv2.putText(frame, fn_name, (x - 10, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
        1,(0, 255, 0))

    # Remove false positives
    if(w * 6 < width or h * 6 < height):
        print("Face too small")
    else:

        # To create diversity, only save every fith detected image
        if(pause == 0):

            print("Saving training sample "+str(count+1)+"/"+str(count_max))

            # Save image file
            cv2.imwrite('%s/%s.png' % (path, pin), face_resize)

            pin += 1
            count += 1

            pause = 1

if(pause > 0):
    pause = (pause + 1) % 5
cv2.imshow('OpenCV', frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(10)
if key == 27:
    break
```

This code will help you to get the cropped images from the webcam and store them in a directory name as face_data for training purpose.
In case, you don't want to train your dataset from webcam, you can simply do one thing:
that just create a directory and create 5-6 sub-directory in it as in Happy, Sad, Angry, Neutral, Calm, etc.
Download the images and put them in corresponding folders for training purpose, now follow this code.

```
## This program first ensures if the face of a person exists in the given image or 
not then if it exists, it crops
## the image of the face and saves to the given directory.

## Importing Modules
import cv2
import os


directory = "C:\\Users\\hp"

## directory where the images to be saved:
f_directory = "C:\\Users\\hp\\face_data/"

def facecrop(image):
   ## Crops the face of a person from an image!

   ## OpenCV XML FILE for Frontal Facial Detection using HAAR CASCADES.
   facedata=    
   "C:\\opencv\\build\\etc\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
   cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(facedata)

   ## Reading the given Image with OpenCV
   img = cv2.imread(image)

   try:    
    minisize = (img.shape[1],img.shape[0])
    miniframe = cv2.resize(img, minisize)

    faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(miniframe)

    for f in faces:
        x, y, w, h = [ v for v in f ]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)

        sub_face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        f_name = image.split('/')
        f_name = f_name[-1]

        ## Change here the Desired directory.
        cv2.imwrite(f_directory + f_name, sub_face)
        print ("Writing: " + image)

except:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    images = os.listdir(directory)
    i = 0

for img in images:
    file = directory + img
    print (i)
    facecrop(file)
    i += 1
```

Comment: I am confused what is the purpose of using v * size in the loop? where size=2 or 4

      face_i = faces[0]
    (x, y, w, h) = [v * size for v in face_i]